# Gratuitous ARP request using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, network-programming, arp

Working on a Windows 2008 server and assigning an IP address locally to a server. Once the IP address is assigned I need all other servers in the subnet to update their ARP caches. This seems to be possible using [Gratuitous ARP](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP) but I'm unable to find out how to send the request. Does anyone have any experience with this ?

Comment: what does this have anything to do with C# or C# 4.0???

Comment: Windows sends a gratuitous arp automatically when a static IP address is changed, when a new static IP address is added, or the machine is booted. Do you really need to force one to be sent?

Comment: @JamieSee, not true for Windows 2008.. GARP changed between 2003 to 2008. devices do not cache ARP which causes the issue, however Clustering technology does update the devices.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5292/Raw-Ethernet-Packet-Sending